# Why are ebx, esi and edi unusable when operating with a stackframe?

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention, stack-frame

I'm having problems operating with such a small number of registers when making a function in assembly - what's inside those registers that's preventing me from using them? Can I copy their contents into a parameter while coding and reset it before exiting the function to not break its purpose?

Comment: They're call-preserved.  All that matters is that when you return to the caller, those registers have the values they had on entry.  You can leave them untouched, or save/restore them however you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why are ebx, esi and edi unusable

This is entirely dependent on the ABI and [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) used by the platform, though, it so happens that most compilers conform to the pattern where the registers `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` are considered volatile across function calls, unlike the other registers.

> Can I copy their contents into a parameter while coding and reset it before exiting the function to not break its purpose?

Yes, in fact, it's a pretty common idiom in x86 code to restore registers that are supposed to be preserved across function calls like so:

```
my_fn:
    push ebx
    push esi


    ; code ...

    pop esi
    pop ebx
    ret
```

Assuming that the `; code ...` part didn't unbalance the stack, `esi` and `ebx` are restored to their old values before leaving the function.